# What is the chance (ignoring anything other than chance) that one out of five teams wins the Stanley cup?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For those curious, I'm referring to the 5 Canadian teams (Montreal, Toronto, Ottawa, Calgary, and Edmonton) in the playoffs for the Stanley Cup this year.

It's been a while since I've taken combinatorics, so I'm trying to wrap my head around how to calculate this. I'm also assuming for simplicity sake that each team has a 50% chance to win their series.

For reference, here are the brackets. https://www.nhl.com/stanley-cup-playoffs

So for starters, knowing that neither of the five teams face off with each other in the first round, every one of them has a 50% chance of advancing to the second round. Assuming all of them make it to the second round, then two of them necessarily have to be eliminated, because you'd have Montreal vs Ottawa and Calgary vs Edmonton. In both of those cases, there's a 100% chance of a Canadian team advancing, with a 50% chance of the remaining team (Toronto) advancing. From there, you'd have a 100% chance of either Toronto or one of Montreal/Ottawa winning the Eastern Conference Finals, and a 50% chance of either Calgary/Edmonton winning.

I can't seem to figure out how to put all the numbers into a calculation though. I *think* that for the first round, since all five teams' outcomes have no effect on the others in that round, that it should be a $1-\frac{1}{32}$ chance of having at least one team advance, but beyond that I can't remember what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that under your model all the teams that enter the playoffs have an equal chance of winning.  As sixteen teams start out, the chance a Canadian team wins is $\frac 5{16}$

Comment: I would have thought that there would be a much bigger calculation for that

Comment: @agent154:  it is that simple if you only care about the winner.  If you ask about the chance for the winner and runner-up to both be Canadian, you have to pay attention to the bracket layout for the sorts of reasons you mention.